# I want to change background of a more than one child on press of one of the special child

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Hello I have just started to learn react native, and i am stuck at this. I am not sure this the right way to do or need to change. Please help.

I have a parent component and a child component. Parent contain flatlist and rendering child. If a child is special then want to change background of multiple child, if not then only his background will change.

```
class Parent extends Component {

 constructor(props){
  a = ['a','h','n','1','2','3'];
  this.state={
   list=a,
  };
}

render(){
 return (
  <View>
   <FlatList
      data={this.state.list}
      renderItem={(item) => (
          <Child name={item['item']} />)} />
  </View>
 )
}
}

class Child extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  this.state={
   itemState:"off"
 }

 pressed(name){
  //if name is alpha it's special change background of multiple.
  //else change background of this only.
 }

 getImage(){
  if(this.state.itemState === "on){
   return require('onImgPath')
  else
   return require('offImgPath')
 }
 render(){
 var imgp=this.getImage();
  return (
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.pressed.bind(this,this.props.name)>
    <ImageBackground source={imgp}> 
     <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  )
 }
}
```

on the press of flatlist item i.e. child i want to change image. which will be based on name of child if its 'a' then all non special child will change background to 'on'. if 'h' then only first half will change to 'on' and other to 'off' and if it's 'n' then all non special will change to off image.

Please advise how to make it work and which way should be proper to handle such kind of situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should precise :

*if the name is alpha it's special change background of multiple.*

**Correction**

This is a *possible* correction to your code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {  StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Text, ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class Parent extends Component {

 constructor(props){
     super(props);

  let a = ['a','h','n','1','2','3'];

   this.state={
     list:a,
   };
}

_renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (<Child name={item} /> );

render(){
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.list}
        renderItem= {this._renderItem}/>
   </View>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state={
  itemState:true,
  }
}

pressed = () => {
  if(this.props.name === 'alpha'){
   // Do stuffs
 }

  this.setState({itemState:!this.state.itemState});
  console.log(this.props.name);  
}

render(){ 
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={()=>this.pressed()} style={{ width: '100%', height: 80 }}>
        <ImageBackground source={this.state.itemState === true ?  require('assets/on.png') :  require('assets/off.png')} style={styles.image}> 
           <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.name}</Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </TouchableOpacity>
     )
    }
   }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
   },
  text : {
   fontSize:16, 
   marginLeft:20, 
   color:'white'
  },
  image : { width: '100%', height: '100%' }
})
```

**Start screen**

[image]

**Clicked on 'n' and '2'**

[image]

**Conclusion**

- you must call 'super' in the constructor
- be aware to close all bracket opened: {}
- look at the difference with your code, learn and enjoy!

**A more precise answer**

If I look to the question in the title of this thread, one solution is to control the state of your children in the parent component. You must think of the behaviour of the children in this case.

This is a solution :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import  {  StyleSheet, View, FlatList, Text, ImageBackground,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

let a = [
  {name :'a',itemState: true,linked:['n','1']}, 
  {name :'h',itemState: true}, 
  {name :'n',itemState: true}, 
  {name :'1',itemState: true}, 
  {name :'2',itemState: true,linked:['h']}, 
  {name :'3',itemState: true}
];

export default class Parent extends Component {

 constructor(props){
   //Never forget to call super()
   super(props);
   this.state={
   list:a,
   listLinked : []
 };
}

//Don't forget to pass the callBack function
//This callBack process the state of items in list
_renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (<Child item={item} callBack={this._callBack}/> );

_callBack = (entrie) => {
//Look if item has linked elements and do the job
if (undefined != entrie.item.linked){
    for(var i=0; i< entrie.item.linked.length; i++){
       var indexLinkedItem = a.findIndex(element => element.name===entrie.item.linked[i]);
       //Here you must think to the behaviour of your function
       //By default, I toggle the actuel state of the linked item
       //If you want to force them to be true or false
       //You have to write : 
       // a[indexLinkedItem].itemState = true
       //or
       // a[indexLinkedItem].itemState = false

         a[indexLinkedItem].itemState = !a[indexLinkedItem].itemState;
        }
    }
//In all case, the state of the pressed item change
   var indexItem = a.findIndex(element => element.name===entrie.item.name);
   a[indexItem].itemState = !a[indexItem].itemState;

//Assign the new list a to the state
  this.setState({list : a});
}

render(){
console.log('main');
 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
        data={this.state.list}
        renderItem= {this._renderItem}
        //Use extraData to be sure flatlist rerender after _callBack
        extraData={this.state}/>
  </View>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
//This is a stateless component

pressed = () => {
 this.props.callBack(this.props);
}

render(){
return (
   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={()=>this.pressed()} style={{ width: '100%', height: 80 }}>
      <ImageBackground source={this.props.item.itemState === true ?  require('assets/on.png') :  require('assets/off.png')} style={styles.image}> 
         <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
      </ImageBackground>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  )
 }
}

//This is the style you can change
//ImageBackground must have size
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 },
text : {
  fontSize:16, 
  marginLeft:20, 
  color:'white'
  },
  image : { width: '100%', height: '100%' }
})
```

From the start screen, when I click on the first item 'a', the state of the linked items 'n' and '1' change too :

[image]

**Conclusion**

You must think about what happens if I click on 'n' now? 
Does it change only the state of 'n' or the state of 'a', 'n' and '1'?
And what happens if you have another item linked with 'a', 'n' or '1'?

Watch the code in action here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmsfhZ53zNE&feature=youtu.be